# Mysql stored function help needed

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

I'm just beginning to learn stored functions in mysql. Can someone please tell me whats wrong with below?

Phpmyadmin says **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'return NAME;
END //' at line 19**

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getName //
CREATE FUNCTION getName(type CHAR(10), id int) RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE NAME CHAR(50);
    CASE type
        WHEN 'offer' THEN 

        SELECT Type_Name INTO NAME FROM otypes WHERE Type_Id = id;          

        WHEN 'service' THEN 

        SELECT ServiceType_Name INTO NAME FROM stypes WHERE ServiceType_Id = id;    

        WHEN 'store' THEN 

        SELECT Store_Name INTO NAME FROM stores WHERE Store_Id = id;    

    END CASE

    return NAME;
END //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a semicolon after `END CASE`:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getName //
CREATE FUNCTION getName(type CHAR(10), id int) RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE NAME CHAR(50);
    CASE type
        WHEN 'offer' THEN 

        SELECT Type_Name INTO NAME FROM otypes WHERE Type_Id = id;          

        WHEN 'service' THEN 

        SELECT ServiceType_Name INTO NAME FROM stypes WHERE ServiceType_Id = id;    

        WHEN 'store' THEN 

        SELECT Store_Name INTO NAME FROM stores WHERE Store_Id = id;    

    END CASE;
--          ^

    return NAME;
END //
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing a `;`

```
END CASE

return NAME;
```

should be

```
END CASE;

return NAME;
```